# How to properly pass a callback-function from swift to c++?

Tags: c++, swift, pointers, callback

I am trying to pass a callback-function from swift-code to c++ code. I am using the current version of Xcode. It works for simple variables, but not for functions so far:

cpp-class.cpp:

```
bool * swiftvar;

void register_var(bool * varpntr){
    swiftvar = varpntr;
    cout<<"registered"<<endl;
}

void switch_var(){
    *swiftvar = !(*swiftvar);
    cout<<"switched"<<endl;
}
```

cpp-class.hpp:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

    void register_var(bool *);
    void switch_var();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and in swift:

```
register_var(&testbool)
print(testbool)
switch_var()
print(testbool)
```

If i try the same for functions (which should be that simple in the current swift version as far as I know), I get errors. So how do I have to pass the function pointer in swift? All methods I found were causing errors. As i read, the old way of defining an UnsafeMutablePointer object an so on became obsolete, but how does it work now? I expect something like:

cpp-class.cpp:

```
void run_func(void * funcpntr()){
    (*funcpntr)();
}
```

cpp-class.hpp:

```
void run_func(void *);
```

(swift-pseudo-code):

```
run_func(testfunc())
```

Or is there even a better solution to run swift-functions from wrapped cpp-code?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's very difficult to tell which parts of your callback example are typos and which are genuine errors. Did you copy-and-paste that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to declare the function type properly in .cpp/.hpp .

.cpp:

```
void run_func(void (* funcpntr)()) {
    (*funcpntr)();
}
```

.hpp:

```
void run_func(void (* funcpntr)());
```

(You can omit the latter `funcpntr` as shown in Jarod42's answer. And this needs to be enclosed in `extern "C" {...}` as shown in the first "cpp-class.hpp:".)

And Swift side:

Function definition:

```
//This needs to be a toplevel function, which means it cannot be a method.
func test_func() {
    //...
}
```

To pass it to `run_func()`:

```
    run_func(test_func)
```

Or you can pass a closure to `run_func`:

```
    //This closure cannot have captured variables.
    run_func {
        //...
    }
```

Comment: There's no need for `.hpp`, the function declaration can be added to the bridging header. Also in the `.cpp` file, `test_run` would need to be embedded within `extern "C"`,  otherwise the name mangling won't generate compatible symbols.

Comment: thank you, I mixed different examples and messed up the correct typedef as you stated above. Since it has to be a toplevel-function, is there any chance to change for example the stringvalue of a textfield in the ViewController-class?

Comment: @archimedes, toplevel-functions can access global variables, but as you know, using global variables would be risky. I would change the cpp function's signature to add another param taking String (it can be `char *`), and pass it to the callback in cpp side. But if you cannot modify the cpp side, you may need to use global variable with extra care.

Comment: @Cristik, "no need" does not mean "should not". And you are right with `extern "C"` thing. I omitted that part as the OP have shown it in the first "cpp-class.hpp" example, but other readers may be confused. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The signature would be

```
void run_func(void (*)()); // Declaration

// Definition
void run_func(void (*funcpntr)()) {
    (*funcpntr)();
}
```

And usage

```
void testfunc(); 
run_func(&testfunc);
```